# Making a login function using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently working on a project that requires a login system that can access information (username, password) through a database using sqlite3. Here is the current login system:

```
def UserLogin():
    un = admin
    pw = password

    try:
        statement = cur.execute("SELECT Username FROM Users")

        for row in statement:
            if un in row:
                print("%s" % un)
                pw_pas = cur.execute("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = %s" % (un))

                if (pw in pw_pas):
                    print("Welcome\n")

                elif pw not in pw_pas:
                    print("Password is incorrect")
                return
        print("Username is incorrect")
    except IOError:
        print("This process could not be executed")

    print("login successful")
```

The problem is that when I run the code I get an error message saying "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: admin". I have entered the username and password into the database but still get this error.

Please help

Comment: Congratulations! You've discovered SQL Injection.  You have sent the word Admin without quotes, and it has been accepted as a column name in your query. A malicious user could use this 'feature' to access, change, or delete any data in your database.  See the answer re: parameters.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** use string substitution for SQL statements. Use parameters.

```
cur.execute("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?", (un,))
```

Comment: @JordanCorfield If you want to know why this is the right approach; I suggest you read up on common security flaws.  the OWASP Top Ten is a great place to start. Good Luck.